# Highchart - Min max and Mean chart

Tags: highcharts

[image]

Is it possible to create min max and mean chart in highchart as shown in above screenshot? I have tried OHLC but it's not same. So let me know if we can customize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use boxplot, with adapted data:

http://jsfiddle.net/G54B6/1/

```
series: [{
        name: 'Observations',
        data: [
            [760, 801, 801, 801, 965],
        ],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
        }
    }]
```

Comment: Is there any option to set same whisker and median line width? As i shown in above snapshot all whiskers of same width. I have tried   plotOptions: {
            boxplot: {
                whiskerLength: '100%'
            }, } . But whiskerLength is more. Is there any way to set length?